# How can I publish my flutter app in Codemagic to their static pages without using Workflow Editor

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, codemagic

I am able to publish my flutter app to the Codemagic static pages.  I go into workflow editor under distribution and I can set it up.  I want to get away from workflow editor and use their `codemagic.yaml` file instead.  When I do that, I don't see how I can add the publish to static pages.  I can't find any documentation on it.  All the documentation says to do it from workflow editor.

Can I configure this in the yaml file?  I want to be able to write scripts with my builds, so I need the yaml option.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Codemagic developer here.

Unfortunately at this moment (May 2022) we provide static pages for quick preview for educational purpose mostly. Advanced users should consider to use professional solutions like Firebase Hosting to host sites.

So this is why we don't support static page deployment with `codemagic.yaml` file, but you can easily publish to Firebase Hosting using preinstalled Firebase CLI tools or to any other services.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer because I really like the simplicity of static pages.  But thanks for answering.